# How to add signature element definition to XSD

Tags: xml, xsd

One of our XMLs is going to have a signature block in the future.

I'm not sure where to put the definition for it into the XSD-file for that.

I tried to put the following at the end (before closing the `<xs:schem>`):

```
<element name="Signature" type="ds:SignatureType"/>
<complexType name="SignatureType">
    <sequence> 
        <element ref="ds:SignedInfo"/> 
        <element ref="ds:SignatureValue"/> 
    </sequence>  
    <attribute name="Id" type="ID" use="optional"/>
</complexType>

<element name="SignatureValue" type="ds:SignatureValueType"/> 
<complexType name="SignatureValueType">
    <simpleContent>
        <extension base="base64Binary">
            <attribute name="Id" type="ID" use="optional"/>
        </extension>
    </simpleContent>
</complexType>

<element name="SignedInfo" type="ds:SignedInfoType"/> 
<complexType name="SignedInfoType">
    <sequence> 
        <element ref="ds:CanonicalizationMethod"/>
        <element ref="ds:SignatureMethod"/> 
        <element ref="ds:Reference" maxOccurs="unbounded"/> 
    </sequence>  
    <attribute name="Id" type="ID" use="optional"/> 
</complexType>

<element name="CanonicalizationMethod" type="ds:CanonicalizationMethodType"/> 
<complexType name="CanonicalizationMethodType" mixed="true">
    <sequence>
        <any namespace="##any" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <!-- (0,unbounded) elements from (1,1) namespace -->
    </sequence>
    <attribute name="Algorithm" type="anyURI" use="required"/> 
</complexType>

<element name="SignatureMethod" type="ds:SignatureMethodType"/>
<complexType name="SignatureMethodType" mixed="true">
    <sequence>
        <element name="HMACOutputLength" minOccurs="0" 
            type="ds:HMACOutputLengthType"/>
            <any namespace="##other" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <!-- (0,unbounded) elements from (1,1) external namespace -->
        </sequence>
    <attribute name="Algorithm" type="anyURI" use="required"/> 
</complexType>

<element name="Reference" type="ds:ReferenceType"/>
<complexType name="ReferenceType">
    <sequence> 
        <element ref="ds:Transforms" minOccurs="0"/> 
        <element ref="ds:DigestMethod"/> 
        <element ref="ds:DigestValue"/> 
    </sequence>
    <attribute name="Id" type="ID" use="optional"/> 
    <attribute name="URI" type="anyURI" use="optional"/> 
    <attribute name="Type" type="anyURI" use="optional"/> 
</complexType>

<element name="Transforms" type="ds:TransformsType"/>
<complexType name="TransformsType">
    <sequence>
        <element ref="ds:Transform" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>  
    </sequence>
</complexType>

<element name="Transform" type="ds:TransformType"/>
<complexType name="TransformType" mixed="true">
    <choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"> 
        <any namespace="##other" processContents="lax"/>
        <!-- (1,1) elements from (0,unbounded) namespaces -->
        <element name="XPath" type="string"/> 
    </choice>
    <attribute name="Algorithm" type="anyURI" use="required"/> 
</complexType>

<element name="DigestMethod" type="ds:DigestMethodType"/>
<complexType name="DigestMethodType" mixed="true"> 
    <sequence>
        <any namespace="##other" processContents="lax" 
             minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </sequence>    
    <attribute name="Algorithm" type="anyURI" use="required"/> 
</complexType>

<element name="DigestValue" type="ds:DigestValueType"/>
    <simpleType name="DigestValueType">
    <restriction base="base64Binary"/>
</simpleType>
```

in the schema tag I have the following:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
```

the W3C checker tells me there are some issues with the namespace. But I'm lost here due to my lack of knowledge about XSD

The Signature part in the XML looks as the following (right before closing the root node)

```
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<SignedInfo>
  <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
  <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
  <Reference URI="">
    <Transforms>
      <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
    </Transforms>
    <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
    <DigestValue>[the digest value]</DigestValue>
  </Reference>
</SignedInfo>
<SignatureValue>[the generated signature]</SignatureValue>
</Signature>
```

What changes do I have to add to my XSD so that the XML with the signature block validates true against the XSD?

Comment: You'll probably have more success if you spend a few hours reading some introductory tutorials on XSD.  The namespace declarations you show don't match up well with the namespace usage in the schema fragment you show, which suggests you may also need to read some tutorials on XML namespaces and how they work.  Good luck!

Comment: thanks! with a basic understanding of the namespaces I could create a valid XSD (see my answer below)

Answer (score 0):

I created a valid XSD with adding the "xs"-namespace to all elements and types in the signature definition and by removing the "ds"-namespace from all elements and types.

I copy & pasted the whole definition from https://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd